# Scrollview autoscroll with enter key in editext android

Tags: android-edittext, android-nestedscrollview

I have a layout in which I have 4 edittext in nestedscrollview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:background="@drawable/logo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="17sp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="labs108.com.dentalstudent.activity.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@id/name"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/mayank_agrawal"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textDirection="ltr"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mobile"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/mobile_no"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textDirection="ltr"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gender"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/gender_text"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textDirection="ltr"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/age"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/age_text"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textDirection="ltr"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/date"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textDirection="ltr"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/explain"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/explain"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textDirection="ltr"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/complain"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/complain_text"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textDirection="ltr"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/upload_pic"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textDirection="ltr"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressbar1"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/pic1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <TextView
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/show1"
            android:text="Show Pic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit1"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textDirection="anyRtl"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressbar2"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/pic2"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/show2"
            android:text="Show Pic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit2"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textDirection="anyRtl"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"

            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressbar3"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/pic3"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/show3"
            android:text="Show Pic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit3"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textDirection="anyRtl"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"

            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressbar4"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/pic4"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/show4"
            android:text="Show Pic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit4"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textDirection="anyRtl"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"

            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/save"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:textDirection="ltr"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

WHen I enter text in edittext and press enter from keyboard, scrollview also scroll and with multiple enter, edittext is completely invisible because of scrolling of scrollview.

is there any thing wrong in layout?